# extern functions in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I would like to write a module that uses a function to be defined by the user. For example:

```
module A
(someFun) where

someFun x = doSomethingWith externFun x
```

I would like externFun to be defined by the user, in the file importing the module A. Is there a way? Or is it just a bad idea?

I could of course pass externFun as an argument to someFun, But there it doesn't look very convenient: the function to be passed would be the same for each call to someFun.

Comment: Some comments from the downvoter would greatly help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answers are wrong: it *is* possible! There's a little-used extension called `ImplicitParams` made exactly for doing this. For example:

```
-- A.hs
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}
module A where
someFun x = ?externFun (?externFun x)

-- B.hs
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}
module B where
import A
main = print (someFun 3) where
    ?externFun = (2*)
```

In ghci:

```
Prelude *B> main
12
```

Voila! More information in the [Hugs manual](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/users_guide/implicit-parameters.html), the [GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#implicit-parameters), and [Implicit Parameters: Dynamic Scoping with Static Types (PDF)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/emeijer/publications/lewis00implicit.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. Is it a good and haskelly way to go? Are there disadvantages of using it over passing the function as a parameter (in terms of design or efficiency)?

Comment: @flagadabla I think it's not very common, but I don't know of any design or efficiency concerns to be wary of compared to passing in a function explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't do this. Passing it as an argument is the way to go. However, you can eliminate the repetition by using partial application. Just do something like this in the other module:

```
import A (someFun)
someFun' = someFun externFun
```

Now you can use `someFun'` everywhere instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should take is as an argument. Why do you think it'd be the same for each call? It works like any other argument.